# Associate an image with a post to show it in a slideshow

Tags: custom-field, slideshow

I'm building a site with a slideshow at the top of the page. I've got a unique situation in which the post that the image in the slideshow links to is not necessarily in the post itself.

There are two requirements:

1. Not all posts should go in the slide show. I need a way to designate a post for display in the slideshow. I was thinking of possibly assigning it a category. The problem with this is that we're already using categories for more traditional reasons. Using categories in this manner seems "hacky" to me, and I'd like to avoid it if possible
2. We need a way to associate an image to the post. This image may not necessarily be in the post itself. I was hoping there was a way to upload an image to a custom field, but I haven't been able to find that yet.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. You could create a custom meta box that has a checkbox for whether or not to show in the slideshow.
2. [Post Thumbnails/Featured Images](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) sound like what you're looking for. Note that images uploaded/attached to a post in WordPress do not necessarily have to appear in the content.

Answer (score 0):

re 1. if you don't want to use a separate category, for example sth like "featured", then I would indeed either use the custom meta box that @helenhousandi suggested or perhaps set up a separate taxonomy for that purpose alone.

re 2. nothing to add to @helenhousandi